# How to get values of checkbuttons from for loop tkinter python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, tkinter

I am new to programming in tkinter and am very stuck on using checkbuttons. I have created multiple checkbuttons in one go, all with different text for each one and a different grid position. However I have no idea how to get the value of each button or how to even set it. I want to be able to get the state/value for each button and if it is checked, then another function is called. How do I set and call the value/state of each button? Can this be done in a for loop or do I have to create them individually?

```
    def CheckIfValid(self, window):
        Class = self.ClassChosen.get()
        Unit = self.UnitChosen.get()
        Topic = self.TopicChosen.get()
        if Class == '' or Unit == '' or Topic == '':
            tm.showinfo("Error", "Please fill in all boxes")

        else:
            QuestionData = OpenFile()
            QuestionsList = []
            for x in range (len(QuestionData)):
                #if QuestionData[x][2] == Topic:
                    QuestionsList.append(QuestionData[x][0])


            for y in range(len(QuestionsList)):
                self.ButtonVal[y] = IntVar()
                Checkbutton(window, text = QuestionsList[y], padx = 20, variable = self.ButtonVal[y]).grid(row = 12 + y, column = 2)
            ConfirmSelection = Button(window, text = "Set Homework", command = lambda: SetHomeworkClass.ConfirmHomework(self)).grid()
            print(variable.get()) #here I would like to be able to get the value of all checkbuttons but don't know how
```

Comment: This is _way too much_ code for the question you're asking. Please provide [mcve].

Comment: initially I included the minimal amount of code but was asked to include the entire class. I have reduced it again.

Comment: Neither of those are [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the list of IntVars either called from a command= in the Checkbutton or in the Button.   Don't know why you are calling another class's object, SetHomeworkClass.objectConfirmHomework(self).  It doesn't look like that will work as you have it programmed, as that is another name space and the list of IntVars is in this name space, but that is another topic for another thread.

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk     # Python2
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk     # Python3

def cb_checked():
    # remove text from label
    label['text'] = ''
    for ctr, int_var in enumerate(cb_intvar):
        if int_var.get():     ## IntVar not zero==checked
            label['text'] += '%s is checked' % cb_list[ctr] + '\n'

root = tk.Tk()

cb_list = [
'apple',
'orange',
'banana',
'pear',
'apricot'
]

# list of IntVar for each button
cb_intvar = []
for this_row, text in enumerate(cb_list):
    cb_intvar.append(tk.IntVar())
    tk.Checkbutton(root, text=text, variable=cb_intvar[-1],
                   command=cb_checked).grid(row=this_row,
                   column=0, sticky='w')

label = tk.Label(root, width=20)
label.grid(row=20, column=0, sticky='w')

# you can preset check buttons (1=checked, 0=unchecked)
cb_intvar[3].set(1)
# show what is initially checked
cb_checked()

root.mainloop()
```